# ASP .Net Core: Post API with Cors with request body giving 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a quite repeated question on SO and almost 7-8 questions already answered but the existing solutions aren't working for me.

**When I run the server with same code over localhost, it works fine. But it doesn't work after deployment and all my POST request with body give 400 bad request errors.**

**Frontend**: Angular 7.x running on `http://localhost:4200`

**Server**: Asp .net Core 3.1 running on Ubuntu machine on AWS via `Nginx` over `Cloudflare` domain server.

**Startup.cs** : Here I'm using the default CORS middleware of ASP. I've also tried writing a custom middleware and a extension method for entertaining CORS requests. I'll also add it if you need that code flow. That also didn't work.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddHealthChecks();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<EcommerceDbContext>();

        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddSession();

        services.AddScoped<EcommerceDbContext>();

        services.AddSwaggerDocument();

        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRequestResponseLogging();

        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(builder => {
           builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
        });
    }
}
```

**PlaceOrderController.cs** : The `/placeOrder` API is not working. Also tried with and without `FromBody` attribute. The log is not getting printed but in `nginx access.log` it says 400 status code.

```
public class PlaceOrderController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public PlaceOrderController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<PlaceOrderController>();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/placeOrder")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PlaceOrder(OrderRequest body)
    {
        // this log is not getting printed
        logger.LogInformation("Hello world" + body.ToString());

        // rest of the code removed
    }
}
```

**OrderRequest.cs** : This is the model for the POST request body. Since my model contains a field with underscore, I've tried with both the native serializer `System.Text.Serialization` and `Newtonsoft.Json` as well. That also didn't work.

```
public class OrderRequest
{
    public OrderRequest()
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty("rate")]
    public double Rate;

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public double Quantity;

    [JsonProperty("cashback_rate")]
    public string CashbackRate;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

**Sample Request Body** : `{"rate":12.0,"quantity":1.0,"cashback_rate":"enterprise"}`

Please help. Close to 4 working days already wasted. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your URL on local host HTTP (not secure) or HTTPS (secure)?  A server will send a 400 error if it is only accepting HTTPS and you send HTTP.  There are other reasons but this is the most likely reason.  When deploy the server is requiring HTTPS.

Comment: @jdweng I tried adding Origin header manually from postman (to simulate cors request) for both http and https, still 400 bad request in postman. My localhost is on http only and server on https.

Comment: You have test locally so the request is good.  You are failing with Postman which is unusual.  Postman is more robust than c# and handle a lot more default conditions.  So I'm suspecting the UserAgent may need to be set (what kind of browser to simulate).  Can you use a sniffer (wireshark or fiddler)and check the useragent with local host.  Then add the useragent as a header to the request in postman and see if you still get 400 with deploy server.

Comment: Are you running with localhost the debug or release executable?  Check the compile date of the exe in both the debug and release and make sure the release is the same time as the debug.  One possibility is you are failing with the release version and passing with the debug version.

Comment: @jdweng I need to make the changes and check. Will reply in a while.

Comment: Maybe have a look into NGINX buffer size config.